# datepicker giving unrecognized selector error with UIControlEventValueChanged

Tags: iphone, datepicker

I am writing a simple datepicker code for iphone but this one error is driving me crazy. Here are two use cases, one where it works and second where it doesn't:

1. working case: 
   When I select a date from picker and  create a UIButton and calls the "-(IBAction)showdate:(id)sender" with  "touch up inside" event of this button. showdate is a simple method which right now shows an alert of selected date.
2. non-working case:
   When I call the same above mentioned method with "Value Changed" event of the picker I get following error:
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType showdate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have tried this with both Interface Builder as well as programmatically but getting similar results.

Could someone please tell me what am I missing here.

thanks,

Rols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing wrong you cant call the IBAction with datePicker like this. For calling a function on value change event of date picker you dont need any button, Do like this.

Use this in your viewDidLoad-

```
[self.datePicker addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(showdate:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

then write this function in your .m file.

```
 -(void)showdate:(id)sender
    {
        //your code.
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help but i am afraid I have already tried this approach and got the same error. here is my viewDidLoad code: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Add the picker
 float height = 216.0f;
 NSLog(@"view didload");
 pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 416.0f - height, 320.0f, height)];
 [pickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(showDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
 [pickerView release];
}  and showdate contains one line of logging : NSLog(@"showDate called");

Comment: You make IBOutlet for datePicker and use property fro same or not.make it property and make connection for same.

Comment: ok.. i got it fixed.. some how.. here is what i did: i had a parent view from where I was calling this view containing the datepicker.. earlier i was doing following to call the view: DatePickerTestViewController *detailViewController = [[DatePickerTestViewController alloc] init]; 
 [self.view addSubview:detailViewController.view]; 
 [detailViewController release]; .. to fix i commented the last line.